# Azure Data Factory Copy Task Creates Gap In IDs

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure DataFactory copy task set up to copy employee data from a MySQL database to a SQL Server database.  The data copies over fine except for the fact that the copy operation creates a huge gap in the ID values when copying.  As you can see in the image here, the ID values jump from 1689 to 2410 without any apparent explanation.  When I select from the table in MySQL the IDs are displayed in the proper sequence, but once I do this copy task it creates this bizarre gap.  I've done quite a bit of googling and reading the docs to try and figure out why this is happening with no luck.  I'd love any help someone could provide.

[image: example]

Comment: are some rows failing in the copy activity? Is ID an auto increment column in sql server?

Comment: I have noticed that some rows do appear to be failing.  However, the target table in the SQL server instance is a holding table, so the ID column is not an identity and is not autoincrement.  Additionally, the gap between 1689 and 2410 is not one where rows have failed, the employee in the 2410 column is the next one following the 1689 row.  So it should be 1689 and 1690.  For some reason the job doesn't reflect that.

Comment: So if the ID column is not an identity and is not autoincrement how are the values allocated?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I'm sorry for my lack of clarity, in the MySQL database the id is treated as an identity and is auto-incremented, so that is how the IDs are being allocated.  On the SQL Server side, I'm trying to copy the MySQL data into a holding table, so the holding table doesn't treat the ids as an identity and does not auto-increment.

Comment: Sounds like the holding table in SQL Server could be a heap, or perhaps has a clustered index ordered by other column(s). Does the gap disappear if you `order by id` in your select statement?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I actually determined the source of the problem, the database I was looking at was a testing instance and the gap existed as a result of some inserts/deletes that were done at some point which created the gap in the ids.  When I ran the copy from a production instance, the ids didn't have this gap.  This was more of a rubber duck debugging problem for sure as it should have been obvious to me that the instance I was using could contain bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@morris295, thank you for updating the source of the problem and resolution in the comments, posted your valuable discussion as an Answer to help other community members.

There were some gaps found in between the IDs range in the testing instance due to some inserts/deletes performed on the data. This issue does not exist in the production instance and Ids did not have any gaps in between.

[image]